# filter onto a prefetch django

Tags: django, django-queryset

Hello I want to know why my queryset don't work.

models.py:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

class Product(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField(primary_key=True)
    price = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()

    stock = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)

    subproducts = models.ManyToManyField(
      "self",
      through='catalogue.ProductToProduct',
      through_fields=('box', 'elements')
   )

   categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category, related_name="products")
```

my queryset:

```
Category.objects.prefetch_related(
        Prefetch(
            "products",
            queryset=Product.objects.all().annotate(effective_stock=....).filter(
                effective_stock__gt=0
            ),
            to_attr="products_bis"
        )
    )
).values('products_bis__pk')
```

I get: django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword **'products_bis'** into field. Choices are: category, id, products, slug

Thank you

Comment: show us complete `Product` model.

Comment: it's done but I don't think its useful

Comment: How to return `Product.objects.annotate()`, then if return not None, how to return `prefetch_related()` without `filter()`. Decompose the task.

Comment: ok I show you in a other way the problem

Comment: I updated my post, and Product.objects.all().annotate(effective_stock=....).filter() return a result, it is not None

Comment: The short answer - you can't do it this way. Prefetch actually works **after** the initial query is executed. You should find another way to achieve what you want. You can ask another question or modify this one if you don't know how to do it. I don't see why you ever need the Category model in this query

Comment: ok thanks, so how I can do for add a extra fields on a related models ?

Comment: As I said, you can ask another question or modify this one with the exact task you are trying to achieve and somebody may be able to help